# QgsComposition loadFromTemplate Method Causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, linux

I'm attempting to write some stand-alone python code that opens a qgis project and print composer template in order to generate pdf figures. I have this running on my Windows 7 machine, but I need to move it onto our Ubuntu Linux server.

The code crashes when trying to load a template into the print composer, printing the following error to the console:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the code I'm trying to run using the python interpreter:

```
from qgis.
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import os

app = QgsApplication(sys.argv, False)
app.initQgis()

os.chdir('/path/to/output')

renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
project_path = "/path/to/project/project.qgs" 
template_path = "/path/to/template/template.qpt"

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(QFileInfo(project_path))

root = project.layerTreeRoot()

layers = []
for child in root.children():
    if child.isVisible():
        layers.append(child.layerId())

renderer.setLayerSet(layers)

template_file = file(template_path)
template_content = template_file.read()
template_file.close()
document = QDomDocument()
document.setContent(template_content)

c = QgsComposition(renderer)
c.loadFromTemplate(document)

c.refreshItems()

map_item = c.getComposerItemById('map')
map_item.setNewScale(14400000000,True)

#export to PDF and also save a QGS file
c.exportAsPDF('Fig' + str(1) + '.pdf')
project.write(QFileInfo('Fig' + str(1) + '.qgs'))

#clear project instance
project.clear()
app.exitQgis()
app.exit()
sys.exit()
```

The line that causes the problem is:

```
c.loadFromTemplate(document)
```

The qpt file was created in Windows, I'm not sure if that would be a problem. The qgs file was also created in Windows and it works fine.

EDIT: 
I figured out that its the ComposerLabel tag in the qpt file that is causing the problem. Also, I'm using QGS 2.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the version of QGIS. I managed to install the long-term release version and the problem went away.