# Loading QgsComposition from template without throwing "QgsComposition constructor is deprecated"?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I Googled the deprecation message and the only result was a [GIS.se question I asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221580/why-do-i-get-a-nameerror-for-qdomdocument-when-attempting-to-programmatically-lo?noredirect=1&lq=1) that referenced the error. Despite this constructor having been deprecated in `QGIS 2.4`, there's a [recent question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216371/qgscomposition-loadfromtemplate-method-causing-segmentation-fault) still using the deprecated construction, and one of the [highest voted answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/82181/36886) on the topic relies on it as well:

```
renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
with open(template_composer, 'r') as template:
    new_composer_content = template.read()
    new_composer_document = QDomDocument()
    new_composer_document.setContent(new_composer_content)
composition.loadFromTemplate(new_composer_document)
```

How should I update this code for PyQGIS versions greater than 2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and with a few tweaks, got it to "work" (or throw that message)

Had a rummage around in the QGIS source code on github, and came across [this commit from earlier this year](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/ab4a83b49bbec04900cb3cd549c91a509e08cdfe)

search the page for QgisComposition and you'll see

```
//! @deprecated since 2.4 - use the constructor with QgsMapSettings
-    QgsComposition( QgsMapRenderer* mapRenderer ) /Deprecated/;
explicit QgsComposition( const QgsMapSettings& mapSettings );
```

The line starting '-' has been deleted. So it looks like you need to pass a [QgsMapSettings](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapSettings.html), not a QgsMapRenderer , to the constructor.